How to make a SQL table look like it comes from the terminal
I have a SQL table that comes from the terminal, and I would like to be able to replicate it "as is" in a LaTeX report. It would help the reader see more clearly and do copy-paste easier for them as well. The table can look like that :
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Name      | char(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| RA        | float    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DE        | float    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

And would I ideally look like that :


Note that tables have rows and columns, not fields and records.

You could include the table as verbatim material:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Name      | char(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| RA        | float    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DE        | float    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}


